# Socket keep alive not working on Linux

Tags: java, linux, sockets, tcp, keep-alive

We have a Java app that uses sockets with TCP keep alive enabled

Socket.setKeepAlive(true)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setKeepAlive(boolean)

Our tests show the keep alive functionality is working correctly on a windows host, but not on a Linux host (Ubuntu Lucid).

Digging in we found that the SO_KEEPALIVE numerical constant used in Java does not seem to match the constant used in Linux

In java: jdk/src/share/classes/java/net/SocketOptions.java:

```
public final static int SO_KEEPALIVE = 0x0008;
```

In Solaris: include/sys/socket.h

```
#define    SO_KEEPALIVE    0x0008        /* keep connections alive */
```

In Linux Sparc, MIPS, Alpha and PARISC: /usr/src//linux-headers-2.6.32-19/arch/sparc/include/asm/socket.h:

```
#define SO_KEEPALIVE    0x0008
```

In other Linux (x86 and amd64): /usr/include/asm-generic/socket.h:

```
\#define SO_KEEPALIVE    9
```

We think this would explain why keep alive isn't working on Linux. Can anyone suggest another cause or a solution?

Cheers
Marc

Comment: the SocketOption value is irrelevant, it is mapped to the platform specific value in the native code.

Comment: What different configurations of host/client have your tried? The timeout for keep alive can vary from platform to platform. It may be that the linux host has a longer timeout, and that the client machine is terminating the connection because it thinks the connection is dead.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you can use "netstat -anpo" on linux to check if the keepalive Timer really turned on for your connection. If it is enabled, it would show "keepalive" in the "Timer" column. Otherwise it would be "off".